# Java EE form authentication invalidates session after leaving authenticated area

Tags: jsf, authentication, jakarta-ee, glassfish, web.xml

I have setup form-based authentication in my JSF application.  I have got it up an running using a JDBC realm and have locked down the /admin/* area to those in the "admin" group.  Everything seems to be working as expected, I can log into, and navigate through the admin section, and my session remains active throughout.  However, as soon as i navigate to a page outside the admin section, the application is logging the user out and invalidating the session. Anything in the user session is lost.  I need the application to keep the user logged in until they manually log out, or the session expires. What can I do to resolve this issue?   I'm using Glassfish if that matters. Thanks!

To reiterate my predicament... In my application, my session scoped beans stay active while navigating between pages, then I log into the secure admin area using java's form authentication and the session still remains active; then I browse between pages in the admin section and the session, again, remains active; and then I leave the admin area and then session is invalidated and ends and the user is logged out.  My thinking is it has to be an issue with the web containers security mechanism, as no where in my code do I tell it to log out or invalidate the session.  So to be specific, my first question i need answered is: Is this the normal behaviour of Java's form based authentication, to log out and invalidate the session when leaving an "unsecured" area, ie a url not specified as requiring authentication?

My web.xml includes the following lines:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Admin Section</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin Section</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description/>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <description/>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>sqlRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?error=true</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description/>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: You state that: _"**the application** is logging the user out and invalidating the session."_ That is your code, so you should fix that yourseld

Comment: This question is quite broad. There's a lot you could easily investigate and exclude yourself. First of all, do you have a minimal understanding of how HTTP sessions and cookies work under the covers? For example, you do know that HTTP cookies are tied to a specific scheme/host/port/path and won't be available on a different one? So e.g. when you navigate from HTTPS to HTTP, the cookies created during HTTPS are unavailable in HTTP? This is not particularly specific to JSF/JavaEE but just to basic HTTP.

Comment: @Kukeltje i didn't write java's authentication module so its not my code. Im asking what my code *should* be to work around it. Thanks for the help though, invaluable advice!

Comment: Then ask the one who did write it. Or do not call that code.

Comment: @BalusC Ive investigated as much as I possibly can, Ive read everything I can find in javas documentation and tutorials, and searched everything I could find on stackoverflow. I'm totally lost as to how to find the answer, so your help would be much appreciated. Ill edit the question to try be more specific. Thanks :)

Comment: @Kukeltje: didn't call it code, called it the application.

Answer (score 0):

It's not super easy to do, but to find the culprit you could attach the GF source in a debugger and then put a breakpoint in the GF code where sessions are invalidated.

To find this point, first call session invalidate manually, then step through the code until you are at a sufficiently low level. Put a break point there, then don't call session invalidate manually anymore, and take your steps to reproduce your initial problem. If the session is indeed invalidated by code, your breakpoint will hit and you can look back in the stack which code called it.

As for your specific question:

> Is this the normal behaviour of Java's form based authentication, to log out and invalidate the session when leaving an "unsecured" area, ie a url not specified as requiring authentication?

No, this is absolutely not normal behaviour.

Comment: I'm giving up (again). I just wrote my own authentication class and used a filter to specify urls requiring authentication. Worked straight up. Only thing I changed was removed security config from web.xml, and changed my userSessionBean from using request.login to manually authenticating user credentials.  If you say its definitely not normal behaviour I will give it another crack later and report back. Cheers!